# Cannot specify additional link file for clang

Tags: c++, linker, clang, linker-errors, clang++

I've successfully compiled my main.cpp with clang, specifying additional include path via the command line options as follows: `clang++ -I ./Dependencies/GLFW/include/ -S .\main.cpp`.

However, when I try to link it by specifying the additional link library by the following command: `clang++ -L ./Dependencies/GLFW/lib/glfw3.lib .\main.s` it gives me a linker error `main-8b7c4e.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glfwInit referenced in function main`.

Any suggestions on what might be wrong? I'm sure that the relative path specified is correct, since the compile command gave me no issues. 
`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  glfwInit();
  std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-L` is for specifying folders to search for libraries in. The compiler ignores directories that don't exist.

Your command line should be:

```
clang++ ./Dependencies/GLFW/lib/glfw3.lib .\main.s
```

Comment: nope still doesn't work. still gives me the same error.

Comment: Any warnings in the compiler output? e.g. there might be a warning about the library being in the incorrect format (`.lib` is probably a visual studio library, you probably want a `.a` library for clang/gcc)

Comment: I replaced the .lib file with a .a file (downloaded from the official glfw page). still doesn't seem to work. Also, now it gives me a warning - ` warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`

Comment: nevermind i guess, I'll just use visual studio *shrugs*

Comment: You've downloaded a 32 bit library, you need a 64 bit one

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please find below link for more detail about glfw header inclusion.

https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html

Comment: Please don't post link only answers, links break then your answer is meaningless